# Tracking Twitter users

Tags: twitter

Is it possible to get the IP address of the person who posted a comment on my Twitter profile?

Comment: How does one post a comment to someone's Twitter profile? Do you mean a mention, a direct message, or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not on your own.

The IP address is only known to Twitter. Twitter values the privacy of their users. They will only reveal the IP address when forced to do so by a court order, and you will only get one when the comment is so bad that it warrants a criminal Investigation.

However, you can report a tweet as abusive to Twitter (click on "More" in the lower-right corner of the tweet). The Twitter admins will then take a look at it and choose to punish the user as they see fit.

Answer (score 2):

Only Twitter have the right to track their users. Simply contact Twitter and try to convince them, I pretty sure your request will get rejected.

The right way to achieve what you want is by contacting the authorities in your country and file a complain of [Cyberstalking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyberstalking)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it's a legal problem, not a technical problem. And it's a very difficult thing to achieve.

You have to go to the court and sue Twitter to give you the IP address. You will spend lots of money and time, and it's very probable you will lose.

One thing you can do, but will depend on the knowledge of the commenter, is to send him a message with a link for a site you can control. If he clicks on the link, he will access your server and you will get the IP address.